# Is there any way of getting rid of the screen mirror with SteamVR in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mirror, steamvr

I'm developing a VR app using the MRTK and Unity. I tried initially with UWP but its limitations are to wide (Microsoft, please do something!) and decided to do it with Steam.

All is working fine when I compile and run the application outside Unity except I get a mirror window on my desktop displaying what's running in VR. I find it really annoying and useless but can't find how to get rid of it. Is it a setting in Steam itself, in Unity or is it something controlled by compilation settings?

Answer (score 0):

It's a StreamVR feature that can be easily disabled.

**While running** Steam VR:

- Go on the *Steam VR Status* popup
- Click on the dropdown
- Uncheck *Display Mirror*